# How can we void a fedex shipment using FedEx API?

Tags: fedex

Can we void a FedEx shipment ? Is this same as cancelling a shipment?

What are the queries to run voiding a shipment in FedEx?

Answer (score 2):

You can delete (or cancel) a FedEx shipment as long as it hasn't been tendered to FedEx. The Shipping API provides a delete shipment functionality which is very straight forward. You may find extra information about it in section 2.3 of the [FedEx Ship Service Documentation](https://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/201408/ShipServiceWSDLGuide_v2014.pdf).

Regards,